# How to sum total hours in a row while skipping certain values?

Tags: excel, time, sum

I study wildlife and currently, I am doing an analysis regarding how long my focal species goes off of the mountain (its main habitat) and into human settlements.
Here is a picture with the data: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zm1t.jpg)
Anyways, as you can see there are three coloured columns. Yellow is data, green is time, and blue is whether the animal is on or off the mountain (with red being when the animal is off).
As you can see, this one particular animal went off on several occasions. In this case, he went off the mountain three times but stayed off at various lengths. As I have thousands of data points, I essentially would like to determine how long each "off the mountain" event lasted. That is, since I consider every time the animal went off the mountain to be a separate event, I would like to determine how long the animal was off the mountain for each excursion, separately. In this case, the animal went off three times and I would like to total those three events individually. 
So, as stated, an event would be every single occasion that the animal left the mountain, stayed there (for however long), and eventually made its way back up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be just to count how many consecutive "off" periods there are in a particular run following an "on" period then multiply by 3 hours 20 minutes which you could do like this (starting in (say) K2)

```
=IF(AND(G1="On",G2="Off"), MATCH("On",G3:G$100,0)*TIME(3,20,0)*24,0)
```

You could take it further by looking at the individual times of the fixes as well to get an upper and lower limit (e.g. for the first excursion it could be between 3 hours 20 minutes and 10 hours 40 minutes roughly).

Upper limit

```
=IF(AND(G1="On",G2="Off"), (INDEX(J3:J$100,MATCH("On",G3:G$100,0))-J1)*24,0)
```

Lower limit

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(G1="On",G2="Off"), (INDEX(J3:J$100,MATCH("On",G3:G$100,0)-1)-J2)*24,0),0)
```

where my column J contains a datetime value formed by adding the date and time in columns A and B together.

[image]

This raises an issue about what happens when the animal is still off-mountain at the end of its data (currently gives #N/A because MATCH is unable to find a cell containing "On"). Would need to decide how to treat this case if it ever occurs in practice.

Note when there is only one off-mountain measurement the lower limit is zero because in theory the animal could have left immediately before the measurement and returned immediately afterwards.

**EDIT**

To address the above issue where the animal is still off-mountain at the end of its data (and looking at the sample data it looks as if a different animal's data is immediately following the first animal's data) you would need this

```
=IF(AND(G1="On",G2="Off"), IFERROR(MATCH(1,(G3:G$100="On")*(E3:E$100=E2),0),MATCH(TRUE,E3:E$100<>E2,0))*TIME(3,20,0)*24,0)
```

which would have to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could argue that you might need to do some averaging for an incomplete off-mountain excursion like this which would make it even more complicated, but this is an Excel answer and can't go too far into the rights or wrongs of the analysis.

Comment: Whilst I agree with how you have undertaken the calculation and your comments, there is a mismatch between what the OP is seeking (length of the OFF intervals) and the data available (snapshots of the ON/OFF state at roughly equal intervals with ~10% missing). With some sort of underlying hypothesis about the length of ON and OFF intervals (ie a model) it might (but only might) be possible to calibrate such a model. Without it, the best that the data can indicate is limited to the proportion of time in each state.

Comment: Clearly the data has limitations but it wouldn't stop OP doing some exploratory data analysis to get an idea of how long and how frequent the periods off-mountain are. I agree a more rigorous analysis looks quite tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Unfortunately, not all fixes are 3 hours and 20 minutes long (collars are never perfect and may miss a fix or be off my several minutes, etc). My underlying hypothesis (which is not really so much of a hypothesis since its quite obvious) is that the animals spend little time off the mountains and will only do so for a few hours at a time. I just need to show it by averaging time spent per "off the mountain" event.

Comment: I don't think it matters that not all fixes are 3 hours 20 minutes long. You're comparing time off mountain with time on mountain and the proxy for that is number of fixes. I can't think of a reason why fixes off-mountain should be over-or under-estimated compared to fixes on-mountain (maybe you can) so comparing number of fixes should be reasonably OK. Having said that I'm not a statistician so others may speak with more authority.

Comment: thank you Tom, I have yet to test out the code (as a bunch of random departmental things suddenly came up) but I will undoubtedly check it out when I get home. Just to make sure, will that code pin point every single 'off event' separately?  That is, if one fix shows up, it will calculate 3:20, but if two come up a few rows later than it will calculate 6:40?

Comment: Yes it does each event separately, so for your example data the first formula will give you 6:40, 3:20 and 10:00 for the first 3 events. You'd have to change G$100 to match the number of rows in your data.

Comment: Good! BTW doesn't allow for any blank lines in the data, wouldn't get the right answer if there were any but could be modified fairly easily.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that there may be a slight issue. (although it would be easier to show a picture). So, the basic formula works, however, Instead of 6:40, 3:20 and 10:00, I get 6.6666...,3.3333....,and 10 for the first three events. The formula that I used is =IF(AND(G1="On",G2="Off"), MATCH("On",G3:G$5931,0)*TIME(3,20,0)*24,0). However, I should note that the time differences between each fix still can vary from one another.

Comment: Yes, it's not really an issue, it's because I've multiplied by 24 to get the result in hours because I think it's easier to work with. If you want it to be displayed as a time, leave out the *24 and format column K as time. Just remember that times in Excel are stored as fractions as a day i.e. 24 hours =1, 1 hour = 0.041667 so they are a little tricky to work with. I will put in the image from my version which looks more or less like yours, except does raise an issue of what happens if the animal hasn't returned from a hunting trip at the end of the data.

Comment: Tom, Thank you so much again for your response, and you absolutely helped when it came to understanding the lower limit results. I just want to make sure that the 3.333 bit will not directly impact the results. the only reason being is that in the end, I will average and sum this data. That is, if 3.33 keeps on coming up, when it should be (for the 1 example 3:19:57), I am afraid that it will stack with minutes less so than hours.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good starting-point would be knowing how you gather these statistics in the first place.

Comment: Hello, Do you mean the data in itself? The data comes from collared animals, so I can determine when the are on or off of the mountain. Really, I just need to assess how long they spent off the mountain on each separate occasion (for example, they may go off for a few hours to raid livestock and then come back up the mountain). So, I just need to determine the total hours per event. For example, as most fixes occur roughly three hours and 20 minutes, if the animal was down there for two fixes "off events" than they would be down for six hours and forty minutes.